# Reverse engineer code to flowchart

Tags: eclipse

I have a program in Java and contains complex logic; by complex logic I mean a lot of conditional statements that make it hard to follow the code sometimes. What I want is a plugin for Eclipse that would get my code and create a flowchart (or activity diagram) for me so that I would be able to go through the flow of my code in a diagrammatic format.

Most importantly this needs to be something that is free as my company doesn't want to spend money on this, otherwise there would be options like Code Rocket for Eclipse from what I found.

Thanks!

Comment: There are some good (free) programs out there which will do this, so the question is - how desperately do you want an Eclipse plug-in? Can you live with a stand-alone program (if so, for which o/s)?

Comment: Hi @Mawg, thanks for your response.  If its a stand-alone program that is fine as long as it reads java code.  We work with Windows 7.  Do you have any experience with some tool that you can share?

Comment: Did you Google at all. I don't code Java, but I quickly found http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsefcg/ "This is an eclipse plugin for generating flow chart diagrams from java code. Those can be build from source code and/or test results": I am aware that there are several available fro C/C++, so there are presumably also several for Java. Happy Googling